# How to adjust UIImageView margin programmatically with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView as part of a UICollectionViewCell that I would like to use to visually display a quantity (like a progress bar). In this case the ImageView and its offset represent the percentage remaining of a given item represented by the cell.

Imagine an image of water inside a glass. When the glass is full you see all of the water texture. When the glass is half full, you see half of the water image. so on and so forth...

I want to adjust the top margin of the ImageView based on the percentage remaining. for example:

```
var image : UIImageView
var item = inventoriedItem(percentageRemaining : 100)

var pctLeft = item.percentageRemaining
pctLeft = 42

// PSEUDOCODE:
image.topMarginOffset = 100 - pctLeft
```

Comment: I think maybe you should set a height and weight for your ImageView. and cover it with an UIView, and change the height or XY point of UIView instead of changing margin of imageView

Comment: I'd like to preserve transparency though, so that you can "see through" the empty texture to the background. Can that be done with another ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adjusting the frame of the UIImageView based on the percentage left.

```
var image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 10, width: 50, height: 100))
var pctLeft = 0.42

//assuming you want a vertical progress bar (like a glass of water).
image.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 10 + (100 * (1 - pctLeft)), width: 50, height: 100 * pctLeft)
```

Here I programmatically push the Y value down based on the reduced size of the bar. Let me know if this is what you were looking for...

Comment: I'll give that a shot! That looks right, but I didn't know which part of the sdk to tap into. I'll report back as soon as I implement this.

Comment: Sure thing. Also, if you created the imageView on storyboard, you could create an outlet and pull it's properties onto variables to provide the appropriate x, y, width, and height for the frame adjustment.